# Looking for similar names and addresses in joined table

Tags: sql-server, group-by, self-join

I've been stuck on this problem for a while and I'm hoping I can get some help here!

In SQL Server 2012 I have two tables, Name (containing Name and ID) and Address (containing ID and AddressID), from which I need to find duplicate records based on similar sounding names, and the same AddressID.

This is my current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.Name, c.ID, c.Name
FROM Name a 
JOIN Address b 
    ON a.ID = b.ID
JOIN Name c 
    ON SOUNDEX(a.Name) = SOUNDEX(c.Name) 
    AND a.ID < c.ID
JOIN Address d
    ON c.ID = d.ID  
WHERE a.Name = c.Name
```

I get returned a table that contains duplicate information: each pair is distinct, but I don't need to know all the possible pairs, I just want a list of the similar names and IDs.

I have been trying to implement GROUP BY and HAVING clauses but I can't seem to get the results I want.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Edit:

```
My current list looks like this:
ID1     Name1       ID2    Name2       AddressID
1       Smith       10     Smythe      8
1       Smith       11     Smithy      8
1       Smith       12     Smythe      8
1       Smith       13     Smithy      8
10      Smith       12     Smythe      8
10      Smith       11     Smithy      8
10      Smith       13     Smythy      8
11      Smith       12     Smithe      8
11      Smith       13     Smythy      8
12      Smith       13     Smythy      8
2       John        14     Jon         9
2       John        15     Jonn        9
...
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
ID1     Name1       ID2    Name2       AddressID
1       Smith       10     Smythe      8
1       Smith       11     Smithy      8
1       Smith       12     Smythe      8
1       Smith       13     Smithy      8
2       John        14     Jon         9
2       John        15     Jonn        9
...
```

I have managed to create a rather inelegant solution by dumping my table in a temp table, then looping through the rows and inserting them in a final table if the ID numbers do not yet exist in that table. It seems to me that there should be a better way of doing it, though!

Comment: So you want it to return something like `Smith Smyth Smythe Smitth`, then `Jon John Jonn`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate result set, with matching address and similar names. You need an Union to get the results

`Select Distinct C.ID, C.Name, D.ID, D.Name From 
Address A
Inner Join Address B On A.AddressID = B.AddressID
Inner Join Name C On A.ID = C.ID
Inner Join Name D On B.ID = D.ID
Union
Select A.ID, A.Name, B.ID, B.Name From
Name A
Join Name B On SOUNDEX(A.Name) = SOUNDEX(B.Name)`

My Comment is still valid though. How do you want your output to be if there are more than one match.

Pardon any syntax error as I could not try running this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But I should have specified how the list should look. Right now, I'm returning just one big list but the IDs and Names aren't matched in four columns. I updated my post, hope you'll take another look at it!

Comment: This should be easy for the name search, however for address search, what if there are more than two matches.

Comment: Edited my answer for your output.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if I completely understand your question as I think my brain has given up for today, do you mean if non-similar names have an AddressID match? I'm looking for those in a separate script that I will hopefully be able to move forward with once I get this one. In this script, there will be many names that have the same AddressID, and I want those be listed below each other like the example. I tried your code and it returns a lot of rows with much the same format as what I have now (it shows every possible combination of numbers for which the name is similar).

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to do it.  DIFFERENCE compares the results of SOUNDEX and rates them from 0 to 4, where 4 is the most similar.  You may need to adjust my criteria to be more or less permissive.

```
DECLARE @Name TABLE (NameID int, Name varchar(50));
DECLARE @Address TABLE (AddressID int, NameID int);

INSERT @Name VALUES (1, 'Smith');
INSERT @Name VALUES (2, 'Smyth');
INSERT @Name VALUES (3, 'Smythe');
INSERT @Name VALUES (4, 'Jones');
INSERT @Name VALUES (5, 'Jonas');
INSERT @Name VALUES (6, 'Johnson');

INSERT @Address VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT @Address VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT @Address VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT @Address VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT @Address VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT @Address VALUES (5, 5);
INSERT @Address VALUES (6, 6);
INSERT @Address VALUES (1, 6);

SELECT  *
FROM    @Name N1
JOIN    @Name N2    ON DIFFERENCE(N1.Name, N2.Name) >= 3 AND N1.NameID < N2.NameID
JOIN    @Address A1 ON A1.NameID = N1.NameID
JOIN    @Address A2 ON A2.NameID = N2.NameID
WHERE   A1.AddressID = A2.AddressID
```

Comment: Thanks! That gives me the same output as my current code, though. I updated my post to hopefully give a better idea of the output I now have and what I want.

Comment: Okay, I read your edits, and now I'm a bit more confused.  Your edits show nothing with respect to the Address, which you said was important.  And your 2nd sample output has data in it that is not part of your 1st sample output.  So that doesn't help clarify anything (to me at least.)  Can you give sample input and expected output?

Comment: I edited my post to hopefully clarify a bit, but I came up with a solution that works for my purposes. If you have time to give any insight on how to do it with a SELECT statement that might be helpful for future readers, though?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (you may want to add additional unduplication rules to the first part):

```
Select *
, RowNumber() over (partition by Sound order by NamePopularity desc, ID) as RowN
into #temp1
from (
   Select ID, Name, SoundEx(Name) as Sound
   , count(ID) over (partition by Name) as NamePopularity
   from Name
) a

Select a.ID, a.Name, b.ID, b.Name from #temp1 a
inner join Name b
on soundex(a.Name) = soundex(b.Name) and a.name <> b.name
where a.RowN = 1
```

Will choose the most common name per sound group, then join all the other names in the sound group to that.  Drops names that are alone in their sound groups.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising, I'll take a look at it over the weekend!

Comment: No, it didn't fix my problem. I managed to come up with a solution, but thanks for your help!

Comment: @florida88 Sorry this didn't work, but glad to hear you figured it out.  Next time, feel free to let us know what wasn't working for you so edits can be made.